# Unity/C# Weird glitch in FPS controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a weird glitch, when i walk down from a corner (i dont press jump), the player will falling down with very fast speed. If i jump, then everything goes normal. (Its Quill18 FPS controller, i learn from there so thats why i dont use the built in controller instead)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;    
[RequireComponent (typeof(CharacterController))]
public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float movementSpeed = 5.0f;
    public float mouseSensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 20.0f;

    float verticalRotation = 0;
    public float upDownRange = 60.0f;

    float verticalVelocity = 0;

    CharacterController characterController;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
//     Screen.lockCursor = true;
       characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
       // Rotation

       float rotLeftRight = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
       transform.Rotate(0, rotLeftRight, 0);

       verticalRotation -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
       verticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(verticalRotation, -upDownRange, upDownRange);
       Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(verticalRotation, 0, 0);

       // Movement

       float forwardSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * movementSpeed;
       float sideSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed;

       verticalVelocity += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;

       if (characterController.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump"))
       {
          verticalVelocity = jumpSpeed;
       }

       Vector3 speed = new Vector3(sideSpeed, verticalVelocity, forwardSpeed ;

       speed = transform.rotation * speed;

       characterController.Move(speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is something anomalous you're seeing? I mean, you'll reach a given downwards velocity sooner from a standing fall than from a jump, that's just how kinematics works.

Comment: Yes, if i don't jump, just step down from upstairs it's almost like a teleport to the floor.

Comment: Okay, so I'm not a Unity developer and I don't know this for sure, but maybe the problem is that the y location is measured relative to the height of the ground currently under the character? So your character actually maintains a constant y position as you step off the ledge and no acceleration is happening, just the location of y=0 has shifted lower.

Comment: This depends on how you've implemented `CharacterController` I suppose, specifically the `Move` method.

Comment: That's a good guess Asad, alternative could be that your y-velocity/acceleration is very high but controller code is preventing you from falling through the ground. When you step off a ledge the fall is almost instant due to the high velocity. Depends if you've implemented a terminal velocity and how far the fall is (you should be able to see some intermediate frames, i.e. not completely instantaneous if the fall is far enough).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every frame you're running this line:

> verticalVelocity += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;

Thus, you're gaining "momentum" each second, and it wont stop ever until you jump because you're "resetting" the Y velocity to a normal value. I've ran into this problem before, and it can be fixed simply by only adding the Y velocity when you're not grounded. You can use Raycast to check if you have ground, and if you dont, increase `verticalVelocity` by that amount.

Comment: Thanks for helping, even tho i am a beginner, so may i ask for code to put in the script? If it does not take long for you.

Comment: If you're a novice I suggest to dont ask for code, it feels a lot cooler to get things by yourself. What I can tell you, though, is that you can use a Raycast to check if you are on the ground, and if so, dont add `verticalVelocity`, the documentation you need is here [Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) . I hope it helps you!